# rtl8822be wifi driver ubuntu 20.04 hp 15-da1009ne

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 via upgrading from 19.10. the problem was that I was trying to solve Bluetooth issue(No Bluetooth driver found). But happen to lose the wifi driver :(

Here is the log

```
sudo lshw -C network

 *-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
```

I was trying to install with the instruction on https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new but no success. Any help would be appreciated. (I wonder how can I reinstall the original ubuntu drivers? That was working for wifi)

---

PS: Why did this question get negative mark?

Comment: This isn't a tech support site. Try [su] instead.

Comment: Use GRUB settings:
This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70981885/4219630

Answer (score 1):

Now it is 4 years gone and developers managed to understand the issue and solved it in the 22.04 version. I use 22.04 installation from scratch and all working.

Answer (score 0):

Go Back Linux Kernel to Linux 5.3.0-46-generic

Comment: Do you think it is really an answer?